# Thymeleaf tag dose not working in html() javascript

Tags: javascript, html, thymeleaf

I try to retrieve the json data and write the value in HTML page

In the HTML page, works fine for example,

```
   <span th:text="#{info.name}"> : </span>
```

However, I wanted to send the data from the javascript as below, nothing returned.

```
     <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){ 
           $("#nameLabel").html("<span th:text='#{info.nameLabel}'></span>");
                    }); 
     </script> 
                    
     <div > 
        <span id="nameLabel"></span> 
     </div>
```

Is it possible to add Thymeleaf tag from HTML() method?

I appreciate any help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf is a server-side template engine. This means that it processes your code and transpile that into an output which the browser can run.

If you want to run JS in Thymeleaf, you will have to enter into the TEXTUAL mode and write your JS in a compatible way.

But remember - this JS you can write there is not inside a `<script>` tag - instead they are .js files in the server.

Here is an example from the documentation:

> ```
> var greeter = function() {
>
>     var username = [[${session.user.name}]];
>
>     [# th:each="salut : ${salutations}"]    
>       alert([[${salut}]] + " " + username);
>     [/]
>
> };
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use like this:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
   var text = [[${info.nameLabel}]];
   ....
</script>
```